# How to add tags to a parsed tree that has no tag?

Tags: stanford-nlp, text-parsing

For example, the parsing tree from Stanford Sentiment Treebank

`"(2 (2 (2 near) (2 (2 the) (2 end))) (3 (3 (2 takes) (2 (2 on) (2 (2 a) (2 (2 whole) (2 (2 other) (2 meaning)))))) (2 .)))"`,

where the number is the sentiment label of each node.

I want to **add POS tagging information to each node**. Such as:

`"(NP (ADJP (IN near)) (DT the) (NN end)) "`

I have tried to directly parse the sentence, but the resulted tree is different from that in the Sentiment Treebank (may be because of the parsing version or parameters, I have tried to contact to the author but there is no response).

How can I obtain the tagging information?

Answer (score 1):

I think the code in edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.BuildBinarizedDataset should be helpful.  The main() method steps through how these binary trees can be created in Java code.

Some key lines to look out for in the code:

```
LexicalizedParser parser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(parserModel);
TreeBinarizer binarizer = TreeBinarizer.simpleTreeBinarizer(parser.getTLPParams().headFinder(), parser.treebankLanguagePack());
...
Tree tree = parser.apply(tokens);
Tree binarized = binarizer.transformTree(tree);
```

You can access the node tag information from the Tree object.  You should look at the javadoc for edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree to see how to access this information.

Also in this answer I have some code that shows accessing a Tree:

[How to get NN andNNS from a text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889335/how-to-get-nn-andnns-from-a-text/36928287?noredirect=1#comment61426024_36928287)

You want to look at the label() of each tree and subtree to get the tag for a node.

Here is the reference on GitHub to BuildBinarizedDataset.java:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/BuildBinarizedDataset.java

Please let me know if anything is unclear about this and I can provide further assistance!

Comment: Sorry that maybe I mislead you by the question. I have edited it. I want to add POS tagging information to each node. Such as `"(NP (ADJP (IN near)) (DT the) (NN end)) "`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to download the [Stanford Parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)

Set up

```
private LexicalizedParser parser;
private TreeBinarizer binarizer;
private CollapseUnaryTransformer transformer;

parser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(PCFG_PATH);
binarizer = TreeBinarizer.simpleTreeBinarizer(
      parser.getTLPParams().headFinder(), parser.treebankLanguagePack());
transformer = new CollapseUnaryTransformer();
```

Parse

```
Tree tree = parser.apply(tokens);
```

Access POSTAG

```
public String[] constTreePOSTAG(Tree tree) {
    Tree binarized = binarizer.transformTree(tree);
    Tree collapsedUnary = transformer.transformTree(binarized);
    Trees.convertToCoreLabels(collapsedUnary);
    collapsedUnary.indexSpans();
    List<Tree> leaves = collapsedUnary.getLeaves();
    int size = collapsedUnary.size() - leaves.size();
    String[] tags = new String[size];
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> index = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int idx = leaves.size();
    int leafIdx = 0;
    for (Tree leaf : leaves) {
      Tree cur = leaf.parent(collapsedUnary); // go to preterminal
      int curIdx = leafIdx++;
      boolean done = false;
      while (!done) {
        Tree parent = cur.parent(collapsedUnary);
        if (parent == null) {
          tags[curIdx] = cur.label().toString();
          break;
        }

        int parentIdx;
        int parentNumber = parent.nodeNumber(collapsedUnary);
        if (!index.containsKey(parentNumber)) {
          parentIdx = idx++;
          index.put(parentNumber, parentIdx);
        } else {
          parentIdx = index.get(parentNumber);
          done = true;
        }

        tags[curIdx] = parent.label().toString();
        cur = parent;
        curIdx = parentIdx;
      }
    }

    return tags;
  }
```

Here is the full source code ConstituencyParse.java that run:
Use param: 
java ConstituencyParse -tokpath outputtoken.toks -parentpath outputparent.txt -tagpath outputag.txt < input_sentence_in_text_file_one_sent_per_line.txt

(Note: the source code is adapt from [treelstm repo](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/treelstm), you also need to replace [preprocess-sst.py](https://gist.github.com/ttpro1995/d80a24c4a127a014c37f3ccf14135fcd) to call ConstituencyParse.java file below)

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.WordTokenFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Word;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.TaggedWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeBinarizer;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructureFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.PennTreebankLanguagePack;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Trees;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreebankLanguagePack;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TypedDependency;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConstituencyParse {

  private boolean tokenize;
  private BufferedWriter tokWriter, parentWriter, tagWriter;
  private LexicalizedParser parser;
  private TreeBinarizer binarizer;
  private CollapseUnaryTransformer transformer;
  private GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf;

  private static final String PCFG_PATH = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz";

  public ConstituencyParse(String tokPath, String parentPath, String tagPath, boolean tokenize) throws IOException {
    this.tokenize = tokenize;
    if (tokPath != null) {
      tokWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tokPath));
    }
    parentWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(parentPath));
    tagWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tagPath));
    parser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(PCFG_PATH);
    binarizer = TreeBinarizer.simpleTreeBinarizer(
      parser.getTLPParams().headFinder(), parser.treebankLanguagePack());
    transformer = new CollapseUnaryTransformer();


    // set up to produce dependency representations from constituency trees
    TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
    gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
  }

  public List<HasWord> sentenceToTokens(String line) {
    List<HasWord> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    if (tokenize) {
      PTBTokenizer<Word> tokenizer = new PTBTokenizer(new StringReader(line), new WordTokenFactory(), "");
      for (Word label; tokenizer.hasNext(); ) {
        tokens.add(tokenizer.next());
      }
    } else {
      for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
        tokens.add(new Word(word));
      }
    }

    return tokens;
  }

  public Tree parse(List<HasWord> tokens) {
    Tree tree = parser.apply(tokens);
    return tree;
  }

public String[] constTreePOSTAG(Tree tree) {
    Tree binarized = binarizer.transformTree(tree);
    Tree collapsedUnary = transformer.transformTree(binarized);
    Trees.convertToCoreLabels(collapsedUnary);
    collapsedUnary.indexSpans();
    List<Tree> leaves = collapsedUnary.getLeaves();
    int size = collapsedUnary.size() - leaves.size();
    String[] tags = new String[size];
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> index = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int idx = leaves.size();
    int leafIdx = 0;
    for (Tree leaf : leaves) {
      Tree cur = leaf.parent(collapsedUnary); // go to preterminal
      int curIdx = leafIdx++;
      boolean done = false;
      while (!done) {
        Tree parent = cur.parent(collapsedUnary);
        if (parent == null) {
          tags[curIdx] = cur.label().toString();
          break;
        }

        int parentIdx;
        int parentNumber = parent.nodeNumber(collapsedUnary);
        if (!index.containsKey(parentNumber)) {
          parentIdx = idx++;
          index.put(parentNumber, parentIdx);
        } else {
          parentIdx = index.get(parentNumber);
          done = true;
        }

        tags[curIdx] = parent.label().toString();
        cur = parent;
        curIdx = parentIdx;
      }
    }

    return tags;
  }

  public int[] constTreeParents(Tree tree) {
    Tree binarized = binarizer.transformTree(tree);
    Tree collapsedUnary = transformer.transformTree(binarized);
    Trees.convertToCoreLabels(collapsedUnary);
    collapsedUnary.indexSpans();
    List<Tree> leaves = collapsedUnary.getLeaves();
    int size = collapsedUnary.size() - leaves.size();
    int[] parents = new int[size];
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> index = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int idx = leaves.size();
    int leafIdx = 0;
    for (Tree leaf : leaves) {
      Tree cur = leaf.parent(collapsedUnary); // go to preterminal
      int curIdx = leafIdx++;
      boolean done = false;
      while (!done) {
        Tree parent = cur.parent(collapsedUnary);
        if (parent == null) {
          parents[curIdx] = 0;
          break;
        }

        int parentIdx;
        int parentNumber = parent.nodeNumber(collapsedUnary);
        if (!index.containsKey(parentNumber)) {
          parentIdx = idx++;
          index.put(parentNumber, parentIdx);
        } else {
          parentIdx = index.get(parentNumber);
          done = true;
        }

        parents[curIdx] = parentIdx + 1;
        cur = parent;
        curIdx = parentIdx;
      }
    }

    return parents;
  }

  // convert constituency parse to a dependency representation and return the
  // parent pointer representation of the tree
  public int[] depTreeParents(Tree tree, List<HasWord> tokens) {
    GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);
    Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependencies();
    int len = tokens.size();
    int[] parents = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      // if a node has a parent of -1 at the end of parsing, then the node
      // has no parent.
      parents[i] = -1;
    }

    for (TypedDependency td : tdl) {
      // let root have index 0
      int child = td.dep().index();
      int parent = td.gov().index();
      parents[child - 1] = parent;
    }

    return parents;
  }

  public void printTokens(List<HasWord> tokens) throws IOException {
    int len = tokens.size();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
      if (tokenize) {
        sb.append(PTBTokenizer.ptbToken2Text(tokens.get(i).word()));
      } else {
        sb.append(tokens.get(i).word());
      }
      sb.append(' ');
    }

    if (tokenize) {
      sb.append(PTBTokenizer.ptbToken2Text(tokens.get(len - 1).word()));
    } else {
      sb.append(tokens.get(len - 1).word());
    }

    sb.append('\n');
    tokWriter.write(sb.toString());
  }

  public void printParents(int[] parents) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int size = parents.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
      sb.append(parents[i]);
      sb.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(parents[size - 1]);
    sb.append('\n');
    parentWriter.write(sb.toString());
  }

  public void printTags(String[] tags) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int size = tags.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
      sb.append(tags[i]);
      sb.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(tags[size - 1]);
    sb.append('\n');
    tagWriter.write(sb.toString().toLowerCase());
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    if (tokWriter != null) tokWriter.close();
    parentWriter.close();
    tagWriter.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String TAGGER_MODEL = "stanford-tagger/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger";
    Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties(args);
    if (!props.containsKey("parentpath")) {
      System.err.println(
        "usage: java ConstituencyParse -deps - -tokenize - -tokpath <tokpath> -parentpath <parentpath>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // whether to tokenize input sentences
    boolean tokenize = false;
    if (props.containsKey("tokenize")) {
      tokenize = true;
    }

    // whether to produce dependency trees from the constituency parse
    boolean deps = false;
    if (props.containsKey("deps")) {
      deps = true;
    }

    String tokPath = props.containsKey("tokpath") ? props.getProperty("tokpath") : null;
    String parentPath = props.getProperty("parentpath");
    String tagPath = props.getProperty("tagpath");

    ConstituencyParse processor = new ConstituencyParse(tokPath, parentPath, tagPath, tokenize);

    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (stdin.hasNextLine() && count < 2) {
      String line = stdin.nextLine();
      List<HasWord> tokens = processor.sentenceToTokens(line);

      //end tagger

      Tree parse = processor.parse(tokens);

      // produce parent pointer representation
      int[] parents = deps ? processor.depTreeParents(parse, tokens)
                           : processor.constTreeParents(parse);

      String[] tags = processor.constTreePOSTAG(parse);

      // print
      if (tokPath != null) {
        processor.printTokens(tokens);
      }
      processor.printParents(parents);
      processor.printTags(tags);
      // print tag
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int size = tags.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
         sb.append(tags[i]);
         sb.append(' ');
      }
      sb.append(tags[size - 1]);
      sb.append('\n');


      count++;
      if (count % 100 == 0) {
        double elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0;
        System.err.printf("Parsed %d lines (%.2fs)\n", count, elapsed);
      }
    }

    long totalTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.err.printf("Done: %d lines in %.2fs (%.1fms per line)\n",
      count, totalTimeMillis / 100.0, totalTimeMillis / (double) count);
    processor.close();
  }
}
```